# Shaders turns transparent

Tags: rendering, shaders, transparency

I am struggling to make this object fully opaque when rendering. It shows up fine before but once I render it, it becomes transparent. I noticed that on the shaders, the texture is also semi transparent but the original image is not. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Tiffany, since you didn't show us your shader node tree or any other settings, pls provide your blend file so we can check it out on our own. thx.

Comment: Hi, Tiffany, and welcome. At least the shader-node tree is needed to give a rational answer to your question. Consider using  https://blend-exchange.com/ to share your file.

Comment: @Chris  Hello! Thanks for your guys comment. I've attached the shader node tree above in the post. Thank you.

Comment: @RobinBetts Hello! Thanks for your guys comment. I've attached the shader node tree above in the post. Thank you.